# how to add email verification after each sign in?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

This is the scenario that I have got for an only sign in policy:

- user introduces email and password.
- user receives OTP to his signing email address.
- user introduces otp and gets verified.
- user is signed in and token is issued.

Using the policies in the starter pack, I have tried the following:

```
<UserJourney Id="SignIn">
            <OrchestrationSteps>
                <OrchestrationStep Order="1"
                                   Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp"
                                   ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.localaccountsignin">
                    <ClaimsProviderSelections>
                        <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" />
                    </ClaimsProviderSelections>
                    <ClaimsExchanges>
                        <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange"
                                        TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" />
                    </ClaimsExchanges>
                </OrchestrationStep>
                <!-- This step reads any user attributes that we may not have received when in the token. -->
                <OrchestrationStep Order="2"
                                   Type="ClaimsExchange">
                    <ClaimsExchanges>
                        <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId"
                                        TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
                    </ClaimsExchanges>
                </OrchestrationStep>
                <OrchestrationStep Order="3"
                                   Type="SendClaims"
                                   CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />
                <!-- Track that we have successfully sent a token -->
            </OrchestrationSteps>
```

The problem is that I am stack at this point: I have changed the following technical profile:

```
            <TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email">
                <DisplayName>Local Account Signin</DisplayName>
                <Protocol Name="Proprietary"
                          Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
                <Metadata>
                    <Item Key="SignUpTarget">SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange</Item>
                    <Item Key="setting.operatingMode">Email</Item>
                    <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccountsignin</Item>
                    <Item Key="IncludeClaimResolvingInClaimsHandling">true</Item>
                </Metadata>
                <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
                <InputClaims>
                    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName"
                                DefaultValue="{OIDC:LoginHint}"
                                AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
                    <!--InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" /-->
                </InputClaims>
                <OutputClaims>
                    <!--OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="Verified.Email" Required="true" /-->
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName"
                                 Required="true" />
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="password"
                                 Required="true" />
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" />
                </OutputClaims>
                <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
                    <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="login-NonInteractive" />
                </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
                <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
            </TechnicalProfile>
```

But the user verifies the email first then, asks for username and password, so there are 2 places where to put the email address (wrong), and the verification comes before the authentication. How do I fix this? I don't need a custom email verification, just the standard will do.

Update,
This is my userjourney now:

```
 <UserJourney Id="SignUpOrSignInMFAOption" DefaultCpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer">
  <OrchestrationSteps>
    <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">
      <ClaimsProviderSelections>
        <!-- <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="FacebookExchange"/> -->
        <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" />
      </ClaimsProviderSelections>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>


    <!-- This step reads any user attributes that we may not have received when authenticating using ESTS so they can be sent 
      in the token. -->
    <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <Preconditions>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
          <Value>authenticationSource</Value>
          <Value>socialIdpAuthentication</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
      </Preconditions>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>

    <!--Sample: If uses is enrolled for MFA, ask the user to select the preferred method-->

    <!-- Throw error if control was bypassed -->

    <!-- Phone verification: If MFA is not required, the next three steps (#5-#7) should be removed.
         This step checks whether there's a phone number on record,  for the user. If found, then the user is challenged to verify it. -->

    <!-- Save MFA phone number: The precondition verifies whether the user provided a new number in the 
         previous step. If so, then the phone number is stored in the directory for future authentication 
         requests. -->

    <!--Sample: MFA with email-->
    <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="Email-Verify" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="EmailVerifyOnSignIn" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>

    <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />
```

Technical profiles:

```
    <TechnicalProfile Id="EmailVerifyOnSignIn">
      <DisplayName>EmailVerifyOnSignIn</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.selfasserted</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="readOnlyEmail" />
      </InputClaims>
      <OutputClaims>
        <!-- Required claims -->
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="isActiveMFASession" DefaultValue="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="readOnlyEmail" PartnerClaimType="Verified.Email" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
        <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteMFAMethod"></ValidationTechnicalProfile>
      </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
      <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-MFA" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
```

Session Mananagement Provider

and it crashes, never gets the email validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found exactly what I was after here: https://github.com/sluggishsloth/Email-OTP/tree/master/policies/sign-in-with-email, there is a small bug but I got it working more or less, the bug is that you need to take an extra space when copying and pasting the OTP, otherwise, it will error. Maybe it was working for me at some point because I was removing spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Use this [sample](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/mfa-email-or-phone) and remove the phone MFA steps.

Then you will have email MFA for every sign-in.

Comment: the problem is that there is no base policy, extensions or localization files. If you pick the ones from the starter package, it errors because of missing claims and so, once you start modifying those, you create a mess

Comment: Always start with the MFA starter pack.